# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPError'

Tags: python, gspread

I made a Worksheet class using the spread python library. here is my code:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import time
import gspread
import requests
import os

DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)

class Wksh:

    credentials_google_sheet = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'credentials/gs_credentials.json'),['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials_google_sheet)    

    worksheet_id = None
    sheet_name = None
    sheet = None

    def __init__(self,wksh_id,sh_name):
        while True:
            try:
                self.worksheet_id = wksh_id
                self.sheet_name = sh_name
                self.sheet = self.gc.open_by_key(wksh_id).worksheet(sh_name)
                break
            except (gspread.exceptions.HTTPError, gspread.exceptions.requests, gspread.exceptions.RequestError) as e: 
                if e[0] == 401:
                    self.gc.login()
                elif e[0] == 500:
                    time.sleep(10)
                else:
                    print 'init'
                    print e
                    break
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                time.sleep(10)
            except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
                time.sleep(20)

    def write(self,cell,value):
        while True:
            try:
                self.sheet.update_acell(cell,value)
                break
            except (gspread.exceptions.HTTPError, gspread.exceptions.requests, gspread.exceptions.RequestError) as e:
                if e[0] == 401:
                    self.gc.login()
                elif e[0] == 500:
                    time.sleep(10)
                else:
                    print 'write'
                    print e
                    break
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                time.sleep(10)
            except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError as e:
                time.sleep(20)
```

This works fine but whenever there is a request error, even though I try to catch the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RequestError' or 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPError'
```

Why is this happening? Do I need to use `self.` before the exceptions?

Thanks

Comment: Well [that module doesn't contain an `HTTPError`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/exceptions.py). Maybe you want [`urllib.error.HttpError` from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError)?

Answer (score 2):

HTTPError was removed check gspread changes https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/87583c562dd3951122411f7029963e53ef16a610/HISTORY.rst#062-2016-12-20

Here you can see all available exceptions 
https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/exceptions.py

Comment: hey, i just got this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'APIError'. How do I fix this ? please help !!

Comment: this is the line of code: except gspread.exceptions.APIError as e:

Comment: i'm basically catching the exception. I don't know if I am missing an import. I have imported gspread, and from oauth2client.service_account the ServiceAccountCredentials

Comment: please help !! I keep getting this error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'APIError'